# How to loop through specific entries in plugin and edit and save

Tags: plugin-development, modules

I want to update some custom field values on my Entries with data from a third-party API, via a Plugin or Module.

How do I load the relevant Entries, and one-by-one set and save the new data in my Plugin/Module? There could be 1500+ Entries in each operation.

I don't mind at this stage if the logic is in a Controller or Service. Ideally, this work could be triggered from the CP.

I'm familiar with Element/Entry events for saving, etc. but can’t find a starting point outside the normal Element lifecycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [entry queries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#querying-entries) to fetch the entries and the [elements service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html) to save them. You can access the element service using `Craft::$app->elements`. Use `Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);` to save an entry (or any other element).

The best place to put business logic is a service class that you can then call from your controllers. So something like this:

```php
use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;

public function updateEntriesWithCustomInfo()
{
    /** @var craft\services\Elements $elementService */
    $elementService = Craft::$app->elements;

    // add conditions here
    $entries = Entry::find()->limit(1500)->all();

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        // update your field
        $entry->setFieldValue('my_custom_field', 'some_value');
        $success = $elementService->saveElement($entry);
        if (!$success) {
            // saving failed, log error or abort
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this might take a while if you have to process 1500 entries at once. If this isn't a one-off, it would be better to put this in a [custom queue job](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/queue-jobs.html). Then your service method would just find the entries to update and add queue jobs with their IDs to the queue. The queue job can either process one element at a time or a batch of elements (e.g. in batches of 25), depending on your requirements.

Comment: thanks @MoritzLost